# Can't click reCaptcha checkmark box with JS script

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I've been trying to click recaptcha checkmark box through script unsuccessfully for a while now and don't know why:

I've inspected the checkmark box and copied the JS path and stored it into variable captchaBox, and If I run this script through the console when the recaptcha is on screen it does run, but with my script it doesn't.

```
function solveCaptcha(){
    let captchaBox = document.querySelector("#recaptcha-anchor-label")
    captchaBox.click()
}

function clickSomething(){
    let randomBTN = document.querySelector('selector for random button')
    randomBTN.click()
    solveCaptcha() //Here I tried setTimeout(solveCaptcha,3000)
}
```

After I call clickSomething(), which works, the captcha won't solve (it will appear after clicking the button). I tried to put some setTimeout for the captcha so the recaptcha window has some time to pop up and then it can execute the solveCaptcha(), but still doesn't work and I can't figure out how to run it.

Comment: so, you want to click one of those "I am not a robot" things using a script? Can you see the irony?

Comment: The whole point of those captchas are so you *cant* click them automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a Captcha solve provider like 2captcha.
If this is for Recaptcha try https://2captcha.com/p/recaptcha_v2

They will provide you with a JSON code which you can apply to the page and will solve the captcha.
Hope this helps

Comment: If you quit the task and retry, that will make the challenge even more difficult the next time and successfully more difficult every-time. You may want to learn about Captchas and how they work.